# Some type of GROUP BY with COUNT in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

everyone.

I'm new with Cassandra and I got a question.

I asked for a model... [Need to queryng into a column (or collection) in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965182/need-to-queryng-into-a-column-or-collection-in-cassandra/36025371?noredirect=1#comment59704145_36025371)

And now, I want to know if there's a way of know how many coincidences match with my query?

In SQL, I can do something like:

```
SELECT id
       count(1) c
FROM example 
WHERE id = 1 and ((c1 = '1' and c2 = '2') or (c1 = '3' and c2 = '4'))
GROUP BY 
id,
c;
```

And that's return the id and the count of coincidences of the fields.

If c1 = '3' doesn't exist. The count is 1.

There's a way of do this on Cassandra. I know that GROUP BY don't exist in Cassandra. But, some idea?

Thanks a lot, mates :D

Comment: Define own custom function in cassandra, using hashmap. Then select rows, make (id, c) as key, and keep counter as value. Works for sure, but its  a paid to do such stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Try cassandra 3.10 or later. It supports Group By. Here is an [example](http://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/02/18/using-group-apache-cassandara/)